# Not able to follow clean coding principles

Tags: apex

I am a newbie in Salesforce development and the code I write often frustrates me because though it works, somehow I feel it does not follow clean coding principles for example with below code. With the current situation,I am the only solo developer.Can somebody please help me to optimize the below code.I am not sure if this is the correct forum but there must be one for optimizing the bad code and I am planning to create one in a year or two.

```
if(flightId != null && flightId != ''){
                }else if((departureStation == null || departureStation == '') && (arrivalStation == null || arrivalStation == '')){
                }else if((departureStation != null && departureStation !='') || (arrivalStation != null && arrivalStation != '')){
                    for(Booking.SegmentTrip sTrip : trip.segments){

                        if((departureStation != null && departureStation != '') && (arrivalStation != null && arrivalStation != '' )
                            && (departureStation == sTrip.flight.departure.station ) && (arrivalStation == sTrip.flight.arrival.station)){
                            cFlightId = sTrip.flight.id;
                            break;
                        }else if(departureStation!=null && departureStation!= 'undefined' && (arrivalStation==null || arrivalStation=='undefined')
                            && departureStation==sTrip.flight.departure.station){
                            cFlightID = sTrip.flight.id;
                            break;
                        }else if(arrivalStation!=null && arrivalStation!='undefined' && (departureStation==null || departureStation=='undefined')
                            && arrivalStation==sTrip.flight.arrival.station){
                            cFlightID = sTrip.flight.id;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Are you looking for simple improvements like `String.isBlank(x)`, `String.isNotBlank(x)` instead of `x != null && x != ''`, cleaning `undefined` outside the loop so you don't have to compare it on every iteration, etc.?  or are you searching for something more? (such as using maps)

Comment: @SergioAlcocer More is what I am looking for.I would appreciate every inputs which leads to clean coding.

Comment: See e.g. https://refactoring.guru/refactoring/techniques/simplifying-conditional-expressions.

Comment: @SergioAlcocer How do I use Maps or clean undefined here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of Boolean and branching optimization comes down to thinking about the "truth table" carefully, and applying logic. First, for the repeated checks about the input variables, we can define a single Boolean that can be used over and over again:

```
Boolean hasFlightId = String.isNotBlank(flightId);
Boolean hasDeparturesStation = String.isNotBlank(departureStation);
Boolean hasArrivalStation = String.isNotBlank(arrivalStation);
```

However, we won't need this by the end, because we're going to reduce the complexity of your branches to a minimum.

---

If a branch only has two possible conditions, we can omit the other situation. For example, you end up saying:

```
} else if(!hasDeparturesStation && !hasArrivalStation) {
} else if(hasDeparturesStation || hasArrivalStation) {
```

If the first branch is not met, then the second condition must be met.

We know this from the following truth table:

| NOT AND OPERATION | departures=false | departures=true |
| --- | --- | --- |
| arrivals=false | true | false |
| departures=true | false | false |

We can therefore omit that condition:

```
} else if(!hasDeparturesStation&!hasArrivalStation) {
} else {
```

We can also use de Morgan's Laws here, which states that NOT A && NOT B is the same as NOT (A OR B) and NOT A OR NOT B is the same as NOT (A AND B):

```
} else if(!(hasDeparturesStation|hasArrivalStation)) {
```

This is optional, as it really doesn't save much typing here.

Finally, the big chunk of if statements at the end can be combined using the XOR operator. This returns true only if one bit is set (i.e. one Boolean value is true) in the comparison. We use this fact to check for a null value and if the value matches at the same time.

```
!(String.isNotBlank(departureStation) ^ departureStation == sTrip.flight.departure.station)
```

Here, if departureStation is null and matches, or if departureStation is null and does not match, we end up with a false value. If departureStation is not null and matches, or if departureStation is null and does not match, we end up with a true value.

Note that because we already checked if at least one parameter isn't null/blank before starting this loop, we know that this can only match if there's a non-null parameter. You might want to sit down with some paper and simulate the entire thing to verify what I'm saying. It's helpful even for advanced developers to do this to check an algorithm.

In the end, we end up with this beautiful code:

```
if (String.isNotBlank(flightId)) {
} else if(!(hasDeparturesStation|hasArrivalStation)) {
} else {
    for (Booking.SegmentTrip sTrip : trip.segments) {
        if (!(String.isNotBlank(departureStation) ^ departureStation == sTrip.flight.departure.station) &
            !(String.isNotBlank(arrivalStation) ^ arrivalStation == sTrip.flight.arrival.station)) {
            cFlightId = sTrip.flight.id;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, note the use of `|`/`&` instead of `||`/`&&`. In this case, we don't need the shortcut behavior, so we can use normal Boolean operators instead. This is kind of unusual in Apex, but works just as well.

We can also de Morgan's Laws one last time, resulting in:

```
if (String.isNotBlank(flightId)) {
} else if(!(hasDeparturesStation|hasArrivalStation)) {
} else {
    for (Booking.SegmentTrip sTrip : trip.segments) {
        if (!((String.isNotBlank(departureStation) ^ departureStation == sTrip.flight.departure.station) |
            (String.isNotBlank(arrivalStation) ^ arrivalStation == sTrip.flight.arrival.station))) {
            cFlightId = sTrip.flight.id;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox for your valuable inputs. definitely learned something here.I will test the code ,the only thing i am curious here is about 'undefined'.One of the two inputs(ArrivalStation, DepartureStation) come as 'undefined '.

Comment: @Pseudodarwinist that's likely a problem with your client-side code. "undefined" usually means that you tried to use a variable that hasn't been initialized yet.

Comment: Yes,it seems when one of the inputs is coming as undefined ,cFlightId is not set.Since these inputs are passed to Apex methods from LWC and ArrStation and deparStation are not required fields,they pass as undefined .May be i will have to clean the undefined part to make your optimized code work as intended.

Comment: @Pseudodarwinist That's what I'd do. I don't like undefined strings showing up in my data, much clearer if it's just null.